# Enable accents in dvorak layout in WIndows 10

Tags: windows, dvorak

I would like to have latin accents using the dvorak layout in windows 10. I have looked to pages like [this](http://arjenvankol.com/index.php) and [this](http://keyboards.jargon-file.org/#USID), and I have some layouts. You can see this in the figure below.

Nevertheless, I still can't use latin accents (`~`, `^`). How can I use accents in dvorak layout in Windows 10?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com) to create a series of [dead keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) that will allow you to include whatever accents you require.  For example, the following script will allow you to use the <kbd>~</kbd> and <kbd>n</kbd> keys to make **ñ** or **Ñ**.

```
~::
Input, key, L1, {delete}{esc}{backspace}
if(key=="n"){
    Send {Asc 164} 
}
else if(key=="N"){
    Send {Asc 165} 
}
else {
    Send {Asc 126}%key%
}
return
```

The `~::` line grabs the `~` keystroke, then the `input` command grabs the next 1 character (L1) and assigns it to the variable `key`.  The <kbd>Delete</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>,and <kbd>Backspace</kbd> keys are all listed as escape keys, which will return just the original `~` that was typed.  Otherwise, if you type a lowercase `n` the script will send the ASCII code for **ñ** (`Send {Asc 130}`), and typing an uppercase `N` sends the ASCII code for **Ñ**.  Typing anything else returns the `~` and the next letter you had typed (the final `else` command sends the ASCII for `~` followed by the contents of the `key` variable).

For accents that aren't in the base ASCII, you need to use Unicode, like so:

```
^::
Input, key, L1, {delete}{esc}{backspace}
if(key=="u"){
    Send {Asc 150} 
}
else if(key=="U"){
    Send {U+00DB} 
}
else {
    Send {Asc 94}%key%
}
return
```

Note the difference in command when writing the capital **Û**.

You can chain as many of these together you need, using `if ... else if` commands for everything that uses the same dead key stroke.  Just make sure to include the final `else` statement and the `return` command at the end before going on to the next dead key and set of accents.  The downside to this is that you need to explicitly spell out all the dead keys and accented characters you want to use.  Fortunately, they all follow the same pattern, making setting it up simple, if possibly tedious.

---

More on the AutoHotKey `Send` command: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm

More on the AutoHotKey `Input` command: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm

ASCII table: http://www.asciitable.com/

Unicode table: https://unicode-table.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a compose key: The key to the right of the left shift is not used in dvorak, so can be mapped as a compose key. You can use it to create accented characters. e.g. to make:

- `á` type «compose» «a» «'»
- `ö` type «compose» «a» «"»
- `ß` type «compose» «s» «s»
- `û` type «compose» «u» «^»
- `☺` type «compose» «:» «)»
- `→` type «compose» «-» «>»
- `✓` type «compose» «t» «k»

For Microsoft's windows, you will have to add a compose-key tool, it is not builtin. I can not remember what I used, as I only use MS, when I have to. For Debian Gnu/Linux (and most systems using the X windowing system) , it is built in.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Dvorak Layout on MacOsx since 10 years, and I recently also have a PC on windows.
I have manage to create a layout with dead keys using the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Editor.
I have put the source code here : https://github.com/adrienleroy/windows-dvorak-deadkeys-layout