# How to completely substitute the accent keys for spanish á Á?

Tags: autohotkey

I want the RAlt key to behave the same as the ´ key (accent)

The normal behavior for the accent keys is:

- When you press it, nothing is shown
- After that, click a vowel and the letter appears

So, when you click

```
´
a
```

you get: á

When you click

```
´

Shift+A
```

you get: Á

In my AutoHotkey I've tried this:

```
RAlt::´
```

But this happens:

```
´

a
```

And nothing happens

Click this:

```
´

´
```

and this happens: ´´

My workaround is just doing the simultaneous pressings like this:

```
>!a::Send á

+>!a::Send Á
```

And that **kind of works**, but it's not the same behaviour of the accent key in a spanish keyboard.

The goal is put a sticker under the keys with the ñ and the accent

**And anybody being able to use it without further explanation**

Any ideas on how to effectively remap the ´ behaviour in the english keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use AutoHotKey for this; simply install and use the US-International keyboard layout, which will provide the "dead key" accents on the actual accent key, working as you describe (that is, ' followed by a -> á, etc.).

If you *insist* on using AutoHotKey, use the following script as a guide; as provided, it's for allowing me to enter the special characters from Esperanto into a document:

```
#Hotstring ? C * 

::^c::ĉ
::^C::Ĉ
::^g::ĝ
::^G::Ĝ
::^h::ĥ
::^H::Ĥ
::^j::ĵ
::^J::Ĵ
::^s::ŝ
::^S::Ŝ
::~u::ŭ
::~U::Ŭ
```

When AHK is running with this script, I use ^ followed by J to get Ĵ, and so on.

Comment: Oh! didn't know that! 
it works! áéíóú
Does it have a key to produce ñ¿¡ ?

Comment: Ñ/ñ is simply ~ followed by N/n, as you'd expect. The US-International keyboard puts ¿ at RAlt+? and ¡ at RAlt+1

Comment: Being a programmer I need to type things like var1='a'
so that wouldn't work

Comment: To get the accent without the letter, type the accent followed by space - ' plus space is ', so to get e.g., 'a' you would type ', space, a, ', space.

Answer (score 2):

[My answer to a previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46732006/933524) goes over how it works, but code like this can be set up to create dead keys from any keyboard key you would like:

```
RAlt::
Input, key, L1, {delete}{esc}{backspace}
if(key=="a"){
    Send á    ;or Send {Asc 164} 
}
else if(key=="A"){
    Send Á    ;or Send {U+00C1} 
}
else {
    Send %key%
}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how I solved it..

```
:?C*:``a::à
:?C*:``i::ì
:?C*:``e::è
:?C*:``o::ò
:?C*:``u::ù
:?C*:``A::À
:?C*:``I::Ì
:?C*:``E::È
:?C*:``O::Ò
:?C*:``U::Ù

:?C*:^ :: ; Turn ^{Space} into neutral ^, else ^ will be used in next vowel.
    Send, {^}{Space}{BackSpace}
Return

:?C*:^a::â
:?C*:^i::î
:?C*:^e::ê
:?C*:^o::ô
:?C*:^u::û
:?C*:^A::Â
:?C*:^I::Î
:?C*:^E::Ê
:?C*:^O::Ô
:?C*:^U::Û

:?C*:`" :: ; Turn "{Space} into neutral ", else " will be used in next vowel.
    Send, +{'}{Space}{BackSpace}
Return

:?C*:`'a::ä
:?C*:`;a::ä
:?C*:`'i::ï
:?C*:`;i::ï
:?C*:`'e::ë
:?C*:`;e::ë
:?C*:`'o::ö
:?C*:`;o::ö
:?C*:`'u::ü
:?C*:`;u::ü
:?C*:`'A::Ä
:?C*:`'I::Ï
:?C*:`'E::Ë
:?C*:`'O::Ö
:?C*:`'U::Ü

:?C*:' :: ; Turn '{Space} into neutral ', else ' will be used in next vowel.
    Send, {'}{Space}{BackSpace}
Return

:?C*:`"a::á
:?C*:`"i::í
:?C*:`"e::é
:?C*:`"o::ó
:?C*:`"u::ú
:?C*:`"A::Á
:?C*:`"I::Í
:?C*:`"E::É
:?C*:`"O::Ó
:?C*:`"U::Ú

:?C*:`'c::ç
:?C*:`'C::Ç
:?C*:ss\::ß
:?C*:sss::ß
:?C*:ae\::æ
:?C*:AE\::Æ
:?C*:oe\::œ
:?C*:OE\::Œ
```

in some cases I used the ; and ' prefix sign as I didn't want to have to press the : or " (requires an extra shift, and i'm lazy).
I use the same method for special characters like σ, Ω, μ